# Can we show the text in bar of timeline chart?

Tags: highcharts

Can we shoe the text inside the Highchart timeline bar?
for reference please look years into the attached snap.[timeline_spac][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1yvQ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SVGRenderer` tool to render those labels.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d60o35sL/

```
    events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this;

        chart.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
          const x = point.plotX;
          const y = point.plotY + chart.plotTop + point.graphic.height / 3;

          if (point.customLabel) {
            point.customLabel.destroy()
          }
                    
          point.customLabel = chart.renderer
            .text(
              'test',
              x,
              y
            )
            .css({
              color: 'white',
            })
            .add();

          point.customLabel.toFront()

        })
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: When we change browser size, zoom and in case of scrollbar  text goes to overlap.

Comment: @ThakurlalPandey the edit has been made at my answer, please take a look at the demo now.